# Spring Security 6 - Access UserDetails in a OAuth2ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set up an OAuth2Resource Server using Springboot 3 and Spring Security 6.

I was able to configure authentication correctly; I implemented a custom jwt converter, which fetches the user's authorities from my database and assigns them to the security context.

```java
class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    AzureUserService azureUserService;

    public CustomAuthenticationConverter(AzureUserService azureUserService) {
        this.azureUserService = azureUserService;
    }

    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt) {
        // Currently, creates a user in the database, if they don't exist yet. Guaranteed to get a user.
        User user = azureUserService.retrieveOrCreateUserFromJwt(jwt);
        JwtAuthenticationToken authentication = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, user.getAuthorities(), user.getId());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

Now I can protect my routes using authorities. Next step: I'd like to be able to access inside of some route the information about the current user.
However, even after registering my user details service class:

```java
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return provider;
}
```

I cannot access the UserDetails object in my route:

```java
    @GetMapping("/api/admin/you")
    public String showProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
        return "Details"+ userDetails;

    }
```

This will return "Details null".

I'm not sure if UserDetails is not accessible because I'm using this application just as an OAuthResource Server or I haven't configured it correctly.

The implementation of my UserDetails class:

```java
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final User user; // This is your own User entity class

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities();
    }

    // We use OAuth2, hence no need for password
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.getEnabled();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

and the service:

```java
@Transactional
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // Note that Spring calls the unique user identifier "username", but we're working with a unique identifier.
    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(username);

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            return new CustomUserDetails(user);
        }
        else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is my SecurityConfiguration

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Create RequestMatchers out of the Strings
        List<RequestMatcher> publicMatchers = Arrays.stream(publicPaths)
                .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Apply configuration
        http
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                    authorizeRequests

                            // Allow public access to the routes specified in 'publicMatchers' list
                            .requestMatchers(request ->
                                    publicMatchers.stream().anyMatch(matcher -> matcher.matches(request))
                            ).permitAll()


                            // Require authentication for all other routes.
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })


                // Configure the OAuth 2.0 resource server to use JWT tokens provided by Azure AD B2C
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                        oauth2ResourceServer
                                .jwt(jwt ->
                                        // Set the location where the server can find the JSON Web Key Set (JWK Set).
                                        // The JWK Set contains public keys. The server uses these public keys to
                                        // validate the signatures of incoming JWTs, ensuring they were issued by a trusted authorization server.
                                        // In this case, the URI of the JWK Set is provided by the 'jwkSetUri' variable.
                                        jwt.jwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri)
                                                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(customAuthenticationConverter())
                                )
                )
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to use the jwt as a session holder. Thats not how you should use JWT, the roles should be inserted into the JWT, by the authorization server when it creates the JWT, and userdetails is used for session based login. You are trying to mix two different login types. If you need specific info you use the id in the jwt and do a lookup for that specific endpoint. Not use userdetsilsservice.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for your response. A requirement is that I manage the roles on my side. Is it correct to use a JwtAuthenticationConverter to add additional authorities to the security context, like I did?

If using UserDetails in this context is not recommended, I can live with it. I thought it's a convention to configure it too, no matter if we use JWTs or not. Thanks!

Comment: There should be some way to add private claims to access tokens in your authorisation server, and it would be more efficient to fetch these roles from  DB only once per token issuance rather than for each and every incoming request to your resource server(s). I advise that you expose user roles on a REST endpoint and configure your authorization server to call this endpoint (with client_credentials) and add the result to access and ID tokens private claims. Configuring a `Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken>` in resource server(s) should then be straight forward.

Comment: @ch4mp Thank you! I'm not sure it's possible to configure it this way since I'm using Azure for authentication and I'm not aware of such a feature in Azure to allow me to dynamically load the user roles when issuing an access token. Also, performance is not really an issue. I'd rather want to have UserDetails implemented. Any help with this? Thanks!

Comment: `I'd rather want to have UserDetails implemented` were we not clear? UserDetails is used for form login scenarios, not JWT. You are trying to build a custom security solution which is bad practice. Im not going to participate in teaching bad practices and unsecure solutions. And you should adhere to best security practices.

Comment: First, choosing the less efficient solution frequently is a bad choice, and professionally unacceptable. Second, you should ask the question to Google rather than writing "I'm not aware of such a feature in Azure": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible to wire a JPA repository in an authentication converter bean (I do it [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default-jpa-authorities) for instance), but **it is a bad practice which should be reserved to cases where you can't set access token private claims on the authorization server and where you can't use another (more configurable) authorization server in front of it**. In Keycloak, you do this using "[mappers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api)", in Auth0, you write "[actions](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions)", in Azure, you use "[API connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-user-flow)", etc.

It is much more efficient to fetch roles from DB on the authorization server once per token issuance, rather than for each incoming request on resource server(s). You could mitigate that with caches, but creating, maintaining and debugging caches (shared caches in a distributed environment) is always a pain.

Details of a working solution with an authorities converter fetching roles from DB (but again, if you do that, my bet is you'll regret it sooner or later):

```java
static interface AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> {
}

static interface AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public static class PersistedGrantedAuthoritiesRetriever implements AuthoritiesConverter {
    private final UserAuthorityRepository authoritiesRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        final Collection<UserAuthority> authorities = authoritiesRepo.findBySubject(jwt.getSubject());

        return authorities.stream().map(UserAuthority::getAuthority).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public static class JpaAuthenticationConverter implements AuthenticationConverter {
    private final Converter<String, ? extends Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter;

    @Override
    public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public static class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));
        
        ...

    }
}
```